# R - How to determine if every value in column of dataframe is zero?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe and want to determine for a given column if every value in the column is equal to zero.

This is the code I have:

```
z <- read.zoo(sub, sep = ",", header = TRUE, index = 1:2, tz = "", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

if(all.equal(z$C_duration, 0)) 
  C_dur_acf = NA
```

But I am getting an error:

```
 Error in if (all.equal(z$C_duration, 0)) { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
```

The code should return a boolean value (TRUE/FALSE) if the entire column is all zeros.

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all you should read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask a good question; a good question has better chances to be solved and you to receive help. On the other hand a read of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is also good. It explains how to create a reproducible example in R. Help users to help you by providing a piece of your data a desired output and things you have tried so far.

Comment: `z` is a zoo object, not a data.frame.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Yes you're right.  In this case I don't believe it matters because dataframe and zoo object columns can be indexed in the same manner using the '$' operator

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `all` builtin: `all(z$C_duration == 0)`

Comment: Great! Thank you! This was exactly what I needed and the most simple solution here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example by using the iris dataset built in R and `apply` function in addiction with `all` that allows you to test if all elements of the objects you pass in it do respect one or more logical conditions.

Do note that in this case the "objects" is a column of the data frame. The code with `lapply` do the same for every column.

```
lapply(iris[-5], function(x) all(x == 0))
$Sepal.Length
[1] FALSE

$Sepal.Width
[1] FALSE

$Petal.Length
[1] FALSE

$Petal.Width
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: T. Grover wants to check if everything is equal to zero, not greater than or equal zero, but otherwise this answer is great.

Comment: @EliSadoff, I know. OP would provide a piece of data to avoid users to use build in datasets.

Comment: I completely missed that. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

To use all.equal:

```
if(all.equal(z$C_duration, rep(0, length(z$C_duration)){
    C_dur_acf = NA
}
```

In essence all.equal does a pair-wise test. The if statement is failing because `all.equal(z$C_duration,0)` returns: **"Numeric: lengths (##, 1) differ"**

HTH!